# list datatype in java which dosen't add duplicates

Tags: java

Is there any list datatype in java which dosen't add duplicates. I am not worried about the order in which they are inserted in the list but I would like to have a list which dosen't add duplicates. Or might be the case if the same element is present it just overrites it. Is there something already build in JDK or might be in apache commons package.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for a `HashSet<T>`.
If you don't want reference equality, you'll need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Comment: I know Set dosen't allow duplicates but I am looking for something within List.

Comment: Why? If you don't need ordering, a `Set` should be good enough.

Comment: actually it's within a method then i will prepare a set and then convert back to list and then return which i don't think will be effecient..what u say...?

Comment: @Saurabh Kumar: If `Set` does not work for you, you still can explicitly check for existence using `list.contains()` method.

Comment: Change the method signature. Make it return a Set, or a Collection, or an Iterator, since obviously, List isn't the appropriate type to return.